# Raison pour laquelle « é » s'appelle « e accent aigu » et pas « e accent grave »

Tags: prononciation, diacritiques

C'est quelque chose qui m'a toujours gêné : on appelle *é* « e accent aigu » mais c'est en fait une lettre qu'on prononce de façon grave et inversement pour *è*, ou en tout cas c'est l'impression que j'en ai.

Des exemples flagrants de cette différence sont des mots comme : « créèrent » ou « préfère », où le *é* est clairement plus grave que le *è*.

Comment: J'ai bien peur de ne pas comprendre. Pour moi, le "é" a une sonorité plus aigue que le "è", et les mots que tu présentes ne sont pas, pour moi, différents.

Comment: Je n'ai pas compris la 2ème partie de ta phrase. Qu'entends-tu par 'pas différents' ?

Comment: différents au niveau son (le é est plus aigue que le è pour moi), ils ne dérogent pas à la règle (encore une fois, pour moi)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Les langues évoluent et les intonations changent, mais l'origine des accents aigu et grave remonte pratiquement à l'Antiquité. Les accents français ont été hérités principalement du grec ancien, mais également de l'apex latin dans le cas de l'accent aigu.

Alors qu'en latin, l'apex servait simplement à marquer les voyelles longues, les accents du grec de l'Antiquité, langue à accent de hauteur, marquaient les changements d'intonation de la langue. Le système polytonique du grec ancien avait trois accents, dont le tracé représente la modulation vocale<sup>[1](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritiques_de_l%27alphabet_grec#Accents_toniques)</sup> :

L'accent aigu (*τόνος ὀξύς/tónos oksýs*, littéralement « ton aigu ») notait une élévation de la voix, représentée par un trait ascendant (↗).

L'accent grave (*τονὸς βαρύς/tonòs barýs*, littéralement « ton lourd »), qui notait soit une descente de la voix, soit une absence d'élévation, était représentée par un trait descendant (↘). Puisque le grec moderne est une langue à accent d'intensité à système monotonique, personne ne sait exactement comment l'intonation de l'accent grave était réalisée dans les faits.

Enfin, l'accent circonflexe, notant une modulation montante puis descendante, était aussi représenté par un trait similaire (↗↘).

---

1 : [Diacritiques de l'alphabet grec](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritiques_de_l%27alphabet_grec#Accents_toniques), Wikipédia.

Comment: Aussi: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aigu *Accent aigu. Dénomination empruntée aux grammairiens latins (accentus acutus traduisant le oxeia prosôidia du grec) pour désigner l'élévation du son (équivalent en grec ancien à une quinte au maximum d'après Denys d'Halicarnasse) qui constitue le ton ou accent de hauteur.*

Comment: Génial ! Merci beaucoup pour cette réponse, moi qui cherchait des origines acoustiques... ^^

Answer (score 2):

J'ai bien peur que ce ne soit pas une explication qui a à voir avec la langue ou la phonétique, mais bien avec les mathématiques !

---

[image][image]
À gauche, un angle aigu, qui se caracterise par un angle inférieur à 90°
À droite, un accent aigu

---

[image][image]
À gauche, un angle obtus, ou angle grave, qui se caracterise par un angle supérieur à 90°
À droite, un accent grave

Étant un souvenir de cours, je n'ai pas de source pour ces affirmations, mais j'en ai toujours été satisfait...

Comment: J'avais effectivement cette impression... Merci beaucoup !

Comment: Le problème est que la mesure d'un angle est subjective... car on peut mesurer l'angle intérieur ou extérieur... donc l'ange entre 2 droite peut autant être de 45° que 315°... Il y a bien des convention, mais suivant quelle est la droite de référence, cela change... Aussi, il faut une convention qui permet de définir les 2 demi-droites. Celle prolongeant l'accent s’arrête en coupant la ligne d'écriture, mais la deuxième demi-droite étant la ligne d'écriture, est-ce qu'elle va vers la droite ou vers la gauche... ?

Comment: Comme tu dis, je pense que c'est arbitraire...

Comment: Les accents du français viennent des esprits grecs, comme l'explique [la réponse de Kareen](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/19474). L'association entre e accent aigu/grave et e ouvert/fermé n'a rien à voir avc les angles !

Comment: D'autant plus qu'un « angle grave », ça n'existe pas.

Comment: Sympathique, mais je n'ai jamais entendu parler d'angle grave, pour ma part.

Answer (score 0):

Pour moi j'explique cela car l'accent n'indique pas la tonalité du e sur lequel est l'accent mais la tonalité de la syllable suivante.

Dans votre exemple "Valérie", le "rie" se prononce plus aigu que le lé, donc accent aigu, shématiquement il indique bien que cela va monter /.

Dans l'exemple du mot élève, le premier é indique que le "lè" va être plus haut (aigu) et le è indique que le "ve" va etre plus bas (grave).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).