# Nommer ou écrire « au long » le é : « [ə]/[e] accent aigu », « é/e accent aigu » etc. ?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, pluriel, diacritiques, alphabet

Souvent quand on décrit l'*accent aigu* on dit un truc comme « En français, l’accent aigu est placé sur la lettre e (« é ») [...] » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_aigu)), donc l'accent *placé sur* et non pas l'apposition du type d'accent à la lettre comme quand on épelle un mot ou qu'on nomme l'accent, tel qu'on l'a fait dans une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/19461), alors qu'on dit "on appelle é « e accent aigu »". Le *LBU14*, en traitant de l'accent aigu et du grave, commence une phrase par « *È* n'est utilisé que devant [...] » (on utilise l'italique). Le [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9) cite les *Paroles* de Prévert dans le contexte d'une graphie déterminée de la lettre « e » :

> [...] A comme absolument athée
>  T comme totalement athée 
>  H
>   comme hermétiquement athée 
>  **É** accent aigu comme étonnamment athée
>   
>  E comme entièrement athée 
>  pas libre penseur 
>  athée
>   
>  il y a une nuance
>  [...]
>
> Prévert, *La crosse en l'air* (ds. *Paroles*)

Évidemment, on a le mot *athée* en acrostiche et on ne s'étonne pas d'y rencontrer l'accent aigu...

---

- Comment écrit-on au long/nomme-t-on et marque-t-on le *é* dans une phrase : est-ce « é accent aigu » ou
  « e accent aigu », ou indistinctement, a-t-on déjà vu ça avec un [trait d'union](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3361) ou autrement, et prononce-t-on [ə] ou [e] quand on dit « ...accent aigu » dans ce genre d'apposition ?
- A-t-on une consigne générale à donner pour le pluriel « deux [é/e accent aigu] » ?

Comment: Que veux tu dire par "écrit-on au long" ?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression... L'as tu déjà entendu ? Est-ce typiquement Quebecois ?

Comment: @Random Voir ce [Q&A](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/21468/3177) pour éventuellement plus de détails...

Answer (score 4):

Pour moi c'est absolument *"e accent aigu"* et pas *"é accent aigu"* qui signifierait un *e* avec 2 accents aigus. Si l'on considère que *e* et *é* sont équivalents, alors les autres *e* accentués doivent l'être aussi et l'on pourrait écrire "ê accent aigu", ce qui n'a aucun sens. On n'écrirait pas non plus *"Œ dans l'O"*.

Quant au pluriel, je pense qu'il s'agit de *"e accent aigu"* (invariable). Seul *e* pourrait prendre la marque du pluriel mais cela changerait son sens, donc il n'en prend pas. *"Accent aigu"* est la contraction de *"avec un accent aigu"* qui ne peut pas être au pluriel parce que chaque *e* ne peut prendre qu'un seul accent aigu.

> Exemple : Mais que sont toutes ces questions sur les e accent aigu et autres e dans l'o ?

(Humour quand tu nous tiens)

Comment: @Onaeu. Oui je vois très bien ce que tu veux dire mais je n'ai pas d'exemple marquant à l'esprit pour l'instant. Laisse moi quelques heures, voire la nuit pour y réfléchir :-)

Answer (score 1):

Les 2 ne me choquent pas.
On peut tout autant dire (et écrire) :

- « é accent aigu »: il est assez difficile de différencier l'accent aigu de l'accent grave à l'oral, donc il peut être utile de l'expliciter
- « e accent aigu »: qui pour moi, semble le plus logique
- « é »: tout simplement, mais on prend le risque que la personne ne sache pas si c'est un accent aigu ou un accent grave

Ensuite, dans le cas particulier où on épelle un mot, de manière assez rapide, il est courant d'utiliser la 3ème proposition (que l'on constate dans le jeu TV "Motus" par exemple), c'est-à-dire qu'on ne précise pas le type d'accent, mais on le prononce.

Concernant le pluriel, je ne vois pas de différence avec le singulier, si ce n'est la liaison entre "deux" et "e/é"

Par contre, je ne me base que sur mon expérience personnelle, je n'ai pas de source officielle concernant l'usage.

Answer (score 1):

Serge Reggiani [a enregistré *La crosse en l’air* en 1974](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpgmHuqVwR4) (3 ans avant la mort de Jacques Prévert). Vers 15:30 commence la déclaration citée. On entend bien clairement, sans ambiguïté aucune, la prononciation /ə.ak.sɑ̃.te.ɡy/.

Le recueil *Paroles* fut publié initialement en 1946 aux *Éditions du Point du jour*, mais il ne s'agit que d'un recueil de textes publiés séparément depuis les années ’30. *Gallimard*, qui rachète la maison, publie sa première édition du recueil en 1949, et c'est l'édition qui servira de base à la collection de la Pléiade lorsque celle-ci publiera deux volumes dédiés au poète. Les compilateurs de cette dernière édition affirment que les rééditions successives (toujours chez *Gallimard*) corrigeront toujours plus le texte, afin d’en normaliser la langue, l'orthographe, la syntaxe et toutes les petites irrégularités de Prévert, ce qu'ils déplorent. Néanmoins, ils affirment dans le souffle suivant qu'eux-mêmes ont à de rares occasions apporté de légères modifications là où ils les jugeaient nécessaires, ne donnant pas de liste exhaustive de leurs retouches, mais simplement quelques exemples.

Tout ceci pour dire que ce fameux « É accent aigu comme étonnament athée », publié ainsi dans *La Pléiade*, pourrait avoir ou ne pas avoir fait l'objet d'une retouche.

L’accentuation des majuscules est irrégulière, même aujourd’hui mais plus encore dans les siècles du passé, et de strictes normes émises par les autorités compétentes ne suffisent pas à aplanir le panorama éditorial. Pour connaître la fin de l'histoire, il faudrait remonter au manuscrit original de Prévert, que je n'ai pu localiser et dont je n’ai même pas pu valider l’existence. Faute de manuscrit, on pourrait alors comparer l’état des publications successives de *La crosse en l’air* jusqu’à la première édition de Gallimard en 1949, ce qui fut un deuxième échec de ma part. Je ne puis donc affirmer que le vers fut un temps un simple « E accent aigu comme étonnamment athée », mais j’aimerais en avoir le cœur net.

À défaut de documents imprimés, j’y vais donc avec la déclamation de Serge Reggiani, qui me semble plus conforme à mon expérience personnelle (professeurs, famille, voisins, amis) et que je présume aussi acceptée par Jacques Prévert.