# « Écrire au long/tout au long (quelque chose) » pour en détail, entièrement : est-ce courant, régional ?

Tags: adverbes, locutions, régionalismes, abréviations

Au TLFi on a la locution adverbiale « au [long](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/long) » pour « [d]ans toute sa longueur, de bout en bout » ou, au figuré, « [l]onguement, en détail » :

> Le journal l'Abeille de Bar s'emparait de l'aventure, la commentait *au
>   long*, blâmait avec une courtoisie sévère ce qu'il appelait l'incurie
>   de M. le colonel baron de la Gondrée.
>
> [ Courteline, *Train 8 h 47*, tiré du *TLFi* ]

[*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/long/47739/locution?q=au%20long#181276) a *au long, tout au long* pour « dans son entier, complètement », et donne l'exemple « [é]crire un mot tout au long, sans l'abréger » ; qu'on [distingue](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/long/47739/locution?q=au%20long#181277) de la construction « tout au long *de quelque chose* » (longueur, durée).

---

J'ai trouvé des exemples au [Canada](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect1&info0=1) (*écrire au long, appellation au long*) et au Québec ([*mot au long*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1792), [*écrire au long*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2779))  dans le contexte de consignes au sujet des abréviations. Par ailleurs on m'a mentionné ne pas être en mesure de reconnaître immédiatement la locution et on m'a demandé si c'était régional. Personnellement je dis *au long* mais d'entendre *écrire tout au long (qqc.)* n'altère en rien ma compréhension.

---

- De manière contemporaine et usuelle en France (ailleurs aussi),
  reconnaît-on *écrire **au long*** ou plutôt (exclusivement) *écrire
  **tout au long*** ; ou on emploie quelque chose d'autre pour rendre l'idée de *substituer aux abréviations les mots entiers* :
  [dit-on](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9crire%20au%20long%2C%C3%A9crire%20tout%20au%20long%2Csans%20abr%C3%A9viations%2C%C3%A9crire%20sans%20*_NOUN%2C%C3%A9crire%20au%20*_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A9crire%20au%20long%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9crire%20tout%20au%20long%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csans%20abr%C3%A9viations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%C3%A9crire%20sans%20%2A_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20sans%20faute_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20sans%20cesse_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20sans%20crainte_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20sans%20exag%C3%A9ration_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20sans%20retard_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20sans%20fautes_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20sans%20d%C3%A9lai_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20sans%20doute_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20sans%20l%27_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20sans%20erreur_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%C3%A9crire%20au%20%2A_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20au%20premier_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20au%20grand_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20au%20nouveau_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20au%20jeune_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20au%20m%C3%AAme_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20au%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20au%20petit_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20au%20bas_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20au%20Premier_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9crire%20au%20Grand_ADJ%3B%2Cc0) de manière usuelle surtout « écrire sans abréviations » ?
- Existe-t-il une autre expression (qu'*écrire au long/tout au long* ; tel *commenter au long*) composée d'un nom ou d'un verbe et de la locution
  *au long/tout au long* dans le sens de longuement, entièrement, en détail (donc : [nom/verbe] *au long/tout au long*) avec laquelle on serait familier ? (en d'autres termes hormis le contexte de ne pas utiliser d'abréviations, *écrire au long*, est-on familier avec un quelconque autre usage à l'intérieur d'une expression de la locution adverbiale *au long/tout au long* dans le sens présenté ici.)

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement j'utiliserais "écrire en entier" ou "écrire sans abréviations"; même si je comprends la locution "écrire au long", je n'ai pas souvenir de l'avoir entendue en France.

Je ne connais pas d'expression d'usage courant utilisant "au long" comme locution adverbiale.

Comment: Désolé, je n'ai pas suffisamment entendu "tout au long" en situation réelle pour bien en comprendre les nuances.

Comment: Oui, "en entier"

Comment: Pardon, j'avais mal lu. Ajouté une réponse.

Comment: Au long du chemin, nous avons vu des fleurs magnifiques. Ou non?

Comment: @Lambie Je pense que qoba sous-entendait, "au long" utilisé en position finale.

Comment: Oui, je faisais référence à "au long" en tant que locution adverbiale, par opposition à "au long de" (locution prépositive)

Answer (score 1):

Je ne connaissais pas l'expression *un mot **écrit au long*** et je suppose que c'est la même chose pour la majorité des français. Ce que j'utiliserais à la place est ***en toutes lettres*** ou ***en entier***.

Si on soumet ***écrit au long*** à divers moteurs de recherche, la plupart des pages retournées a un lien clair avec le Canada.

Par exemple [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=%22%C3%A9crit%20au%20long%22) trouve quatre occurrences :

[image]

On peut donc en conclure que l'expression est bien connue au Québec alors qu'en France, elle ne l'est que par une minorité de personnes.

On en trouve néanmoins de plus en plus d'occurrences au fur et à mesure que l'on remonte dans le temps, ce qui montre qu'il s'agit d'un usage ancien qui s'est perdu chez nous mais qui a survécu ailleurs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Désolée, mais "écrire un mot au long", c'est exactement ce que l'on dit, en France et en français, pour un mot qu'on écrit sans abréviation.
Comme confirmé par le Larousse (pourquoi donc ne pas s'y fier ?) et par cette page du Btb Termium Plus, paragraphe 1.1.7
https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap%3Flang=fra&lettr=chapsect1&info0=1
Et comme confirmé par moi-même, relectrice et correctrice pour l'édition

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language SE ; voici le [tour] du site.  Il est utile de mettre les passages cités dans la réponse.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).